# Does the "exclude files based on mask" option in Fling ftp actually work?

Tags: windows, ftp

I'm trying to exclude a directory and some files from being copied to an ftp server but the exclude files mask is ignored.

Has anyone had any success in using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similair problem, then took another look at Filezilla, they've added some nice filtering functionality to prevent certain folders appearing in the transfer list.

Answer (score 0):

The exclude files mask prevents upload, but the exclude folders mask does not seem to prevent the scan process. So if for instance you have 1000 subfolders and need to selectively exclude some to speed up the process, no can do as far as I can see. Great program, otherwise.

Filezilla seems to have no ability for automated file transfer and the sole programmer indicates that it's not going to happen.